# Xpath query for 1260 in : <Rep D="SSE" F="10">1260</Rep> in talend

Tags: xml, xpath, talend

This is the first time i'm handling xml data.

My data looks like this:

```
<Sp>
    <D>
        <Lo>
            <Period>
                <Rep D="SSE" F="10">1260</Rep>
            </Period>
        </Lo>
    </D>
</Sp>
```

I'm looking for the xpath query for the value 1260.

I'm using Talend and looping around the xpath which ends in Rep. I have been able to retrieve all other data, for example for D, the xpath query is @D, but how do i get the value 1260 ?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//Rep[.='1260']
```

will select all `Rep` elements with a string value of `1260`.

This XPath,

```
//Rep[@D='SSE']
```

will select all `Rep` elements with an `D` attribute value equal to `SSE`.

It it's `1260` itself you're after, this XPath,

```
//Rep[@D='SSE']/text()
```

will select all text node children of the above `Rep` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The values keep changing and regardless of what the values for D or F are i want to be to pick the number before </Rep> . In this example its 1260, but it changes and is independent. Is there a way to pick up this value each time?

Comment: `//Rep/text()` will select the text node children of all `Rep` elements in the document, regardless of `@D`, `@F`, and the string value of `Rep`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: //Rep/text() didn't work correctly for me, but i think thats because in Talend I'm already looping around Rep... In the end 'text()' worked for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the context `.` is `Rep`, then, `text()` will return the text node children of `Rep`, correct.   Alternatively, `string(.)` will return the string value of the `Rep` element.  Glad you got it working.